# how to get json data from wordpress in ionic 4 app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I have tried many times in my ionic 4 app but didn't recognize what I am doing wrong.
this is my link( `http://www.hellodevs.online/wp-json/wp/v2/` ) to retrieve json data in my ionic 4 app.
The error message i got is here `Http failure response for http://www.hellodevs.online/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed: 0 Unknown Error`
If anyone is there who help  me to get the data then that help will be very grateful to me

provide me the working code.

Comment: Do you have any other errors in the dev tools Console or the Network tab? Anything related to CORS maybe?....

Answer (score 1):

First import `import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';` on your **app.module.ts** and add `HttpClientModule` on your `@NgModule({imports: [HttpClientModule]})` on the same file.

Next, import `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';` on your **page.ts** and add it on the constructor, `constructor(private http: HttpClient)`

Now, you can call it successfully like the sample method below:

```
getSampleWP() {
    this.http.get('http://www.hellodevs.online/wp-json/wp/v2/').subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
      console.log(data);
    }, (error: any) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: use the code same way you are using but get this message:- Http failure response for http://www.hellodevs.online/wp-json/wp/v2/: 0 Unknown Error .  Have you check it on your side is it working for u and if checked then over which platform

Comment: Yes, it is working on my side. I'm using Ionic 4. Did you add it on your app.module.ts? Also, can you include your ionic info?

Comment: Try running your code on using this browser "chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security --incognito", if it runs,
Most likely this is CORS issue, you need to enable CORS in your wordpress API